# Spring Boot datasource and h2 database path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, datasource, h2

In my Spring Boot application, I'm trying to configure the path for H2 database folder. I want to place it by the following path:

```
/home/public/h2
```

The configuration like:

```
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/home/public/h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

leads to the following error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:file:/home/public/h2". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
```

I also tried `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/home/public/h2`  but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how to properly configure the path?

Comment: The tilde `~` expands to your home directory. Assuming your home directory is `/home/public`: unless your database file is in the location `/home/public/home/public/h2`, you should remove either the tilde `~` or `/home/public`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to use **`jdbc:h2:./name`** (explicit relative path), or

set the system property **`h2.implicitRelativePath`** to ***true*** (to prevent this check).

For Windows, an absolute path also needs to include the drive `("C:/...")`.

```
h2.implicitRelativePath=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/home/public/h2
```

**or**

```
h2.implicitRelativePath=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/home/public/h2
```

for more details please check here ...

- https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not clear to me where the `h2.implicitRelativePath=true` must be set. In my Spring Boot `application.properties` file? In case of single property `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/home/public/h2` it doesn't work

Comment: @alexanoid Yes... set it in the `application.properties` try again and i hope you checked that url link.

Comment: I tried the following `h2.implicitRelativePath=true 
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/home/public/h2` My folder `/home/public/h2` is still empty, no database files inside.. What my be wrong ?

Comment: @alexanoid Firstly we have to check h2 database is enabled in your the Application or not. In spring boot by default H2 database is not enabled ,so set it in the `application.properties` as `spring.h2.console.enabled=true` then check the logs for details..

Comment: put this class level annoation on top your class `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2) class YourClassName {}` try this....

Comment: Thanks, the following configuration works fine: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:/home/public/h2/batch_db` Now I have `batch_db` inside of `h2` folder

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your path, one at the beginning, and one at the end.

The first one you're missing, as the initial comment on your question notes, is that ~ is a special path character that refers to your user's home directory.

If your home directory is, say, /home/alexanoid and you want the  database to be in in /home/public/, leave off the ~, as ~/home/public/h2 would mean /home/alexanoid/home/public/h2.

The second problem is that per the documentation, database names must be a minimum of 3 characters, so "h2" is not a valid database name. You'll need to choose a slightly longer database name, e.g., "h2db".

Answer (score -2):

Change from

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/home/public/h2

to:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/home/public/h2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the path `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/home/public/h2` doesn't work